# Order Posts By Custom Field That is an array of objects

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, mysql, meta-query

I have a custom field called "departure_dates" which is an array of objects with the keys "start_date" and "end_date".

as Json, it would look like:

```
  "departure_dates": [
    {
      "start_date": "Dec 11, 2017",
      "end_date": "Dec 11, 2017"
    },
    {
      "start_date": "Dec 21, 2017",
      "end_date": "Dec 29, 2017"
    }
```

I want to intercept a query for a particular post type and sort the list by start_date.

I tried looking at the following meta_query option but it's not seeming to work

```
function show_by_date ( $query ) {

 // only modify queries for 'my_cpt' post type

 if ( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'my_cpt' ) {

    //Get original meta query if there is one
    $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');


            //Add our meta query to the original meta queries
            $meta_query[] = array(
                                'key'=>'start_date',
                                'order' => 'DESC',
                                'orderby' => 'meta_value'
                            );

             $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num'); //probably need this because the value is date

    return $query;

   }
} add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_by_date',  20 );
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You can't sort by a value within a serialised array (which is what your meta value would be). You should store each date as a separate meta value. A variation on that would be just storing the date you need to sort by separately. So have `departure_dates` as a value with all the dates, but also store the first `start_date` separately just for the purposes of sorting.

Comment: Huh. Is there any good way to create a repeater field that stores some of the values in other meta field that isn't obvious to the user? I hate that I have to do it this way but it is what it is.